# I use cakephp and I want host apache windows on godaddy

Tags: php, hosting

I want buy host apache windows but i dont see how to buy.
 I should buy host Linux or Windows order to have Apache server ?
I use cakePHP...

important , i want use apache, if it is on windows then better. I ever dont use linux, i dont sure use it good ><

Comment: Sounds like a job for serverfault.com

Comment: The question is vague.  Are you asking us what server to buy?  What OS you need to run Apache and PHP?  If the latter, any major OS will do.  Check the Apache and PHP websites for what they support.

Comment: This really sounds like something you should ask Godaddy (or, better yet, a better hosting provider... Godaddy has a shady reputation).

Comment: You can recommend for me ? any best hosting, this is first of me . I used windows and apache on localhost.

Comment: @meotimdihia: If you're accustomed to managing the environment yourself and would prefer that level of control, you may want to look into a rackspace style hosting setup, where you basically just get admin access to your own virtual server with prescribed limits on resource usage.  I don't have any specific recommendations, though.

Comment: @David - I've used GoDaddy for many years for dozens of domain registations, Linux and Windows web hosting, DNS service, and email hosting. They've always dealt honestly with me; can you elaborate a bit on your "shady reputation" remark?

Comment: @GZipp: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_Daddy#Controversies | http://princesimon.wordpress.com/2008/12/30/godaddycoms-shady-and-unethical-domain-names-renewal-process/ | http://domainnamewire.com/2008/12/03/standard-tactics-llc-how-godaddy-profits-from-expired-domains/ | Basically, if GoDaddy thinks your hosted domain is profitable, they make it their business to try to take it from you.

Comment: @David - Thanks for the links to the anecdotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that GoDaddy offers Apache on Windows. If you want Apache, choose Linux. If you want IIS (Internet Information Services) choose Windows. If you do decide to go with Windows based hosting though, I would recommend [ReliableSite](http://www.reliablesite.net/v3/shared.asp).